# How do I get text from an html heading in Python using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm currently learning Python, and as a project for myself, I'm learning how to use Selenium to interact with websites. I have found the element through its id in HTML, but when I don't know how to reference the heading inside the element. In this case, I just want the string from `<h4>`.

```html
<div class="estimate-box equal-width" id="estimate-box">
     <a href="#worth" id="worthBox" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <h5>Worth</h5>
            <h4>$5.02</h4>
     </a>
</div>
```

My question is, how do I get python to extract just the text in `<h4>`? I'm sorry if I formatted this wrong, this is my first post. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following xpath.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[id='worthBox']/h4").text)
```

Or following css selector.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#worthBox>h4").text)
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed. Thank you!